# Is it known what Dracula's first name is in Hotel Transylvania?

Tags: hotel-transylvania

Dracula is referred to as either Drac or Dracula throughout the 3 films. However, Dracula is his surname. We know this from quite a few instances, especially in *Hotel Transylvania 2*, and Mavis makes it pretty clear in the first film.

> **Mavis:** Oh! Hi, humans. Everything okay? My name is Mavis Dracula, and I...
>
> <sub>*Hotel Transylvania*</sub>

Is it known what Dracula's first name is or if he even has one?

Comment: He appears to be mononymous; https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjV0s.png - https://archive.org/details/meetmonsters0000pend

Comment: probably "Blah Blah Blah"

Answer (score 1):

Note, Dracula is actually a title, not a name. It means son of the dragon.

In many versions of Dracula stories, he is the undead form of [Vlad Tepes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlad_the_Impaler), also known as Vlad  the Impaler, who historically took the title "Dracula" in life.

Individual remakes, especially comedies,  may change parts of the traditional version. But unless it is explicitly stated otherwise, assume the default.

So, probably, he is called Vlad.

Comment: His dad is called Vlad (Vlad Dracula) in _Hotel Transylvania_. He could be called the same but I don't think we should assume as such given this.

Comment: This feels like an entirely unfounded guess. As such it would have been (at best) a comment